# php timestamp problem

Tags: php, timestamp

i have a "simple" problem with the PHP timestamp (on a linux machine).

I need to get the user birthdate in year-month-date (using 3 menus - html select). When the user is born on 1970-1-1 the timestamp is zero and the application logic gets everything wrong.

How would you deal with this case?

Regards,

Comment: usually you don't take timestamp for birthdays...

Comment: If the application logic gets everything wrong, I suggest changing it. SCNR ;-) Why use a timestamp in the first place? Aren't there actual "date" data types you can use?

Comment: I agree, timestamps not a good combination with birthdates, but if you really need them why not eliminate the '0' position by adding a few seconds to the day?  convert m/d/y + 60 seconds, etc.  Which would never result a 0 timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your dates are between the years 1901-2038 the PHP native `date` functions should work OK. Timestamps should not be used for birth dates. If you need to use dates outside if this range, take a look at the [ADOdb Date Time Library](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/adodb_date_library).

Answer (score 0):

Try using built in DateTime class instead (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)